# Как огрулить время в sql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Нужно округлить в postgres до часов, таким образом:

> 2019-07-24 11:31:22 ->  2019-07-24 12:00:00
>
> 2019-07-24 11:29:22 ->  2019-07-24 11:00:00
>
> 2019-07-24 11:59:22 ->  2019-07-24 12:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно для математического округления штатной функции нет, можно сделать немного магии вокруг штатной функции [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
melkij=> select d, 
    date_trunc('hour', d) + interval '1 hour' * 
        (d - date_trunc('hour', d) >= interval '30 min')::int 
from unnest(array['2019-07-24 11:31:22','2019-07-24 11:29:22', '2019-07-24 11:59:22']::timestamp[]) as s(d);

          d          |     date_trunc      
---------------------+---------------------
 2019-07-24 11:31:22 | 2019-07-24 12:00:00
 2019-07-24 11:29:22 | 2019-07-24 11:00:00
 2019-07-24 11:59:22 | 2019-07-24 12:00:00
```

Суть магии: обрезаем значение до часов и добавляем один час если обрезанное значение превышает исходное более чем на полчаса.

PS: массив с `unnest` просто чтобы не делать табличку

Comment: Можно проще: 
select d, 
date_trunc('hour', d + interval '30 min')

Comment: @msi, хороший вариант, ага. Не догадался до такого